# Running into a 'TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list' error when attempting to add values to numbers in nested lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists, enumerate

I am currently trying to write a code that will take a nested list, see below:

```
example_list = [[ 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                [ 4, 2, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0], 
                [ 0, 4, 2, 3, 5, 0, 0], 
                [ 4, 2, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0], 
                [ 0, 4, 2, 3, 5, 0, 0], 
                [ 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

and do the following:

1. skip the first and last list in the sequence of nested lists.
2. skip the first and the last values greater than 1 in lists 2 through 5. (in the above example it would be numbers 4 and 5).
3. add 1 to the values in lists 2-5 between the first and the last values greater than one.

With assistance from others I have tried the below code:

```
x = 1

for i, sub_list in enumerate(example_list[1:-1], start=1):
    for j, entry in enumerate(sub_list[1:-1][1:-1], start=2):
        if j > 1:
            example_list[j] = round((example_list[j] + x), 3)
        example_list[i][j] += 1
print(example_list)
```

but am running into a `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list` error. I am assuming that it is because I am trying to add a number 1 to my list values, but I can't seem to figure out how to solve it and get my code to do what I'd like it to.

Comment: It looks like `example_list[j]` should be `sub_list[j]` (both times), since `j` is an index into `sub_list`, not `example_list`. I'm voting to close the question since this seems like it's basically a typo. Check out [ask] for tips for future questions, like making a [mre] including only enough code to reproduce the issue and your desired output. See also [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: `round((example_list[j] + x), 3)` This is the problem.  `example_list[j]` is a sublist, therefore `example_list[j] + x` is an error.  You can't add an integer to a list.

Answer (score -1):

```py
x = 1
for i, sub_list in enumerate(example_list[2:5], start=2):
    for j, entry in enumerate(sub_list[2:-2], start=2):
        if entry > 1 and j != 2 and j != len(sub_list) - 2:
            example_list[i][j] += 1
print(example_list)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).